# Is there a Little law for a network of two connected queues?

Tags: stochastic-processes, computer-science, queueing-theory

From Patterson et al' Computer Organization  and Design:

> **Throughput and Response Time**
>
> Do the following changes to a computer system increase throughput,
>   decrease  response time, or both?
>
> 1. Replacing the processor in a computer with a faster version
> 2. Adding additional processors to a system that uses multiple processors  for separate tasks—for example, searching the web
>
> Decreasing response time almost always improves throughput. Hence, in
>   case  1, both response time and throughput are improved.  In case 2,
>   no one task gets work done faster, so only throughput increases.

Although the book doesn't mention, am I right that the above is based on Little's Law for the relation between occupancy, latency and throughput for a single queue? In the book, the queue would be for queuing tasks being processed.

> If,  however,  the  demand  for  processing  in  the  second  case 
>   was  almost  as large as the throughput, the system might force
>   requests to queue up. In this case, increasing the throughput could
>   also improve response time, since  it would reduce the waiting time in
>   the queue. Thus, in many real computer  systems, changing either
>   execution time or throughput often affects the other.

Is the model now a network of two queues: one for processing, and the other for waiting to be processed?

Is there a  result between throughput, latency and occupancy for this network, similar to the little's law for a single queue?

What are some keywords to look up for this network model and its "Little's Law"? And some references?

Thanks.